# Get points over the tangent circle(or oval) and balance poker chips on

Tags: javascript, html, trigonometry, poker

I try to display some chips for a free poker game (HTML/Javascript client, python server) game.
There are seats around the center of the table. 
for each seats, i know cosinus, sinus, radius (distance from the center of the table), and the values/counts chips array.

I try to display each chips aligned and balanced on the tangent at the seat point

In image: (i can't create image so : https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Obw.png )

for now, i wrote this code :

```
function balanced_stack( chips, cos, sin, radius ) 
{
    var html = ''

    // I receive a chips array like [ [ 100, 8 ], [ 200, 10 ], [ 500, 7 ] ]
    // so 8 chips of 100$, 10 chips of 200$ .. etc
    for(var i in chips) 
    {
        var value = chips[i][0]; // the token value
        var count = chips[i][1]; // the token count

        var m = 0; // margin for a single stack
        var left = i * 20 * sin + cos * radius;
        var top = -i * 20 * cos + sin * radius;

        for( var j=1; j<= count; j++ ) 
        {       
            html += '<img style="z-index:'+( parseInt(top) + 9999)+'; left:'+left+'px; top: '+top+'px; margin-top:'+( -2*m )+'px;" \
                            src="/images/chips/'+value+'.png" />'
            m ++;
        }

        return html
    }
}
```

but it's not right balanced and not good looking.

add : the cosinus and sinus can be greater than 1 and less than -1 because table may be oval

Comment: Consider using Flash for this. The programming language for Flash, called ActionScript, is relatively easy to learn. I mean managed to get 95% on my uni coursework without any prior experience. The reason I say to use AS is because using JS opens the application up to lots of hacks. I mean, for example, you can type JS into the URL of the current page to alter the page you are currently on, or switch it off, or see the source code. With AS they cannot do this. All they need is to have Flash installed. They either can play it without being able to hack it so easily or can't play it at all.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: i know actionscript is a better way to work trigonometry, but i really want to make this game in pure HTML/javascript and it's the python server that control every actions, no possible hack, javascript just display game elements

Comment: ok well so long as its secure there should be no problem. Just thought I'd put my point forward for you to consider is all.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: I work on an another project, an 2D FPS online game, that use actionscript :) of course that's pretty cool for trigo and security and we can work with sockets ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you ellipse is defined by {a*cos(x),b*sin(x)}, the tangent is {-a*sin(x),b*cos(x)}. Using a definition that combines the ellipse's axes with the sine/cosine of the angle around the table does not allow you extract that easily. Besides, it seems a bad idea to call that quantity sin/cos since they are restricted to the domain -1 to +1 by their mathematical definition...

Comment: thanks you, i will try with the ellipse definition. Any idea about the balancement ?

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean by balanced, maybe you mean the equation for that tangent: {a*cos(x),b*cos(x)}+d*{-a*sin(x),b*cos(x)} where d is a parameter for the distance form the point on the ellipse that you are considering...

Comment: all right for the tangent, i mean balanced, a human and ordered repartition of chips

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved the problem of the tangent with the equation of SEngstrom.
All chips are aligned on the right tangent. You can see here : [image]

```
function( chips, cos, sin, radius ) 
{
    var html = ''

    // Considering the equation for the tangent {a*cos(x),b*cos(x)}+d*{-a*sin(x),b*cos(x)}
    var a = 1.6; // x coefficient for the ellipse
    var b = 1; // y coefficient for the ellipse


    // I receive a chips array like [ [ 100, 8 ], [ 200, 10 ], [ 500, 7 ] ], so 8 chips of 100$, 10 chips of 200$ .. etc
    for(var i in chips) 
    {
        var value = chips[i][0]; // the token value
        var count = chips[i][1]; // the token count

        var m = 0; // margin for a single stack

        var left = i * 20 * sin * a + cos * radius * a; 
        var top = -i * 20 * cos * b + sin * radius * b;

        for( var j=1; j<= count; j++ ) 
        {       
            html += '<img style="z-index:'+( parseInt(top) + 9999)+'; left:'+left+'px; top: '+top+'px; margin-top:'+( -2*m )+'px;" \
                            class="chip chip_'+value+'" src="/images/chips/'+CHIPS.COLORS[ value ]+'.png" />'
            m ++;
        }       
    }
    return html
}
```

But as you can see, there is a blank space between each single stack, because a chip have width of 20px, with a regular cos/sin it's ok but here, the distance between each single stack is amplified by the ellipse coefficient (i * 20 * sin * **a**)

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions a bit blindly, and I wrote: (that seems to work)

```
var left = (i * ((20*a) - 20) * sin * a) + (cos * radius * a); 
var top = -(i * ((20*a) - 20) * cos * b) + (sin * radius * b);
```

Can you explain me why that works? I'm mathematically weak.

with 20 fake players around the ellipse table (a=1.6, b=1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: the second term for (left,top) in your code finds the center of the stack. To that you want to add stacks along the tangent. Since your stacks are defined by a pixel width, the form of the term to add to the center point can have the convenient form of i*pxwidth*{nx,ny}, where nx and ny are the (x,y) components of the normalized tangent vector, 'i' is an integer counting up the individual stacks, and pxwidth is the desired pixel width. If sin and cos are true sine/cosines, (-sin,cos) is already a normalized vector since sin^2+cos^2=1.

What I don't understand in your code is the ((20*a)-20) which equals 20*(a-1). Some sort of correction factor for a>1. It is not symmetric for b, but then it would be zero for b=1...